# CouchDB PouchDB Database Design

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchbase, data-modeling, pouchdb

I come from a RDBMS and MongoDB background and can't get my head around the flat Couchbase database.
I am working on an educational app, where students (around 10000) will access "their individual study material " and solve it. Since the application works offline too, I need to keep Couchbase as the remote database and PouchDB as local in mobile and keep them in sync.

Use Cases:

1. If a question is added on the remote server, it should get synced locally to PouchDB.
2. If a student marks any question "important" or "doubt", it should get synced to the remote Couchbase database in the student's private space.

The schema which I can think after researching from SO is that I maintain an individual database for each student (1 bucket for 1 student) so that the syncing can be done very quickly.

The other model can be 1 bucket containing all the students as different documents. In this case, every question will be replicated as a sub-document for every student's document.

What can be the optimal database design at the Couchbase Server. Shall I go for the first or second approach or some other approach as per your suggestions?

Comment: Couchbase is limited to 10 buckets. So per-user bucket isn't possible. CouchDB (not CouchBase) can be used as per-user database.

Comment: Using one single bucket for all the data. And individual documents for each students is the solution I am considering right now. Will it be fine?

Comment: Yup. Don't forget to use filtered replication for offline sync. You don't want to save all your database on every mobile client.